# ToUnicode doesn't return correct characters

Tags: winapi, keyboard, hook, keyboard-hook

I tried to call the `ToUnicode` inside a low level keyboard hook and print the character(s) it returned. However, it seems that the function doesn't take into account whether special keys, such as shift or caps lock were pressed, so the output is the same as from `MapVirtualKey` function with current key's virtual code passed as parameter.

For example (`pressed keys => characters returned by ToUnicode`):

```
abcd => abcd (correct)
[caps lock]abcd => abcd (wrong: should be ABCD)
ab[holding shift]cd => abcd (wrong: should be abCD)
```

How I call the function (inside the hook procedure):

```
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* pressedKeyInformation = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

    BYTE keysStates[256]; // 256 bo tyle virtualnych klawiszy wpisze GetKeyboardState

    if(!GetKeyboardState(keysStates))
        //error
    else
    {
        WCHAR charactersPressed[8] = {};

        int charactersCopiedAmount = ToUnicode(pressedKeyInformation->vkCode, pressedKeyInformation->scanCode, keysStates, charactersPressed, 8, 0);

        //std::wcout << ...
    }
```

Later I noticed that calling `GetKeyState` with any virtual key code passed as parameter (e.g. `VK_RETURN`, `VK_SHIFT`) before `ToUnicode` causes it to return the correct character, e.g.:

```
abcd => abcd (correct)
[caps lock]abcd => ABCD (correct)
ab[holding shift]cd => abCD (correct)
```

It also returns properly keyboard locale dependent keys pressed with AltGr then, e.g. `[AltGr]a => ą`.

The above example isn't entirely correct, since there appears another problem - if e.g. caps lock was pressed, the next character still depends on its previous state, only the latter characters are affected, e.g.:

```
abcd => abcd (correct)
(caps lock is off)[caps lock]abcd => aBCD (wrong: should be ABCD)
(caps lock is off)ab[caps lock]cd => abcD (wrong: should be abCD)
```

Have you any idea why the `GetKeyState(<whatever>)` fixes one of the problems and what's the cause of the latter caps lock (and other special keys) problem?

Comment: Call both `GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT)` and `GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)` before calling `GetKeyboardState`. Your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is not clear. Are you responding to `WM_KEYDOWN`?

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani Yes, I'm responding to `WM_KEYDOWN`. I'll change the code once i'll be home, so in a couple of hours.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani It works perfectly now, thanks. But what do these calls actually do? I believe `GetKeyState(key)` updates `key`'s state internally, am I right? I can't find any clue on msdn. You should post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

Windows documentation suggests `GetKeyboardState` and `GetKeyState` return similar result for the correspond keys, and this is true when these functions are used in a Windows message loop, where keyboard messages are properly translated.

In this case however, we have a hook function, `GetKeyboardState` doesn't properly fill the keyboard. Calling `GetKeyState` first, will change the keyboard state, the subsequent call to `GetKeyboardState` will work as expected. I don't know why!

Other oddities, `GetKeyState` returns `SHORT` value, while `GetKeyboardState` fills `BYTE` array. But this shouldn't make a difference since we are only interested in high and low bits.

```
HHOOK hook;
LRESULT CALLBACK hook_procedure(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if(code == HC_ACTION)
    {
        if(wparam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kb = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lparam;
            BYTE state[256] = { 0 };
            wchar_t str[10] = { 0 };
            GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
            GetKeyState(VK_MENU);
            GetKeyboardState(state);
            if (ToUnicode(kb->vkCode, kb->scanCode, 
                state, str, sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str) - 1, 0) > 0)
            {
                if(kb->vkCode == VK_RETURN) std::wcout << "\r\n";
                else std::wcout << str;
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hook, code, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One note for displaying the characters returned by `ToUnicode` - according to msdn: `However, the buffer may contain more characters than the return value specifies. When this happens, any extra characters are invalid and should be ignored.`, so it'd be nice if you'd display only `N` characters, where `N` is a value returned by `ToUnicode`.

Comment: @Jason, yes that makes sense. Does this work with `AltGr` as well?

Comment: If you meant whether dead keys produce a single character, the answer is yes, but only if the dead key could be combined with another pressed key - according to msdn: `The most common cause for this [i.e. ToUnicode buffer contains >= 2 characters] is that a dead-key character (accent or diacritic) stored in the keyboard layout could not be combined with the specified virtual key to form a single character.`By the way, if we have to follow the rules, you should `return CallNextHookEx` if `code < 0`, before intercepting any keys, as specified in documentation of the hook proc.

Comment: Also, if there were copied 8 characters to the str buffer, then `str[8] = 0` would cause undefined behaviour. However, still: `this buffer may be returned without being null-terminated even though the variable name suggests that it is null-terminated.`.

Comment: Okay, I added an extra index to the buffer.